# Why line 3 gives an error: use of uninitialized value of size 8?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning pointer in C. I tried to let the pointer b in update() point to an integer directly without an int varibale(somewhere in the memory, just an experiment), but when I did that it shows the `ERROR: Use of uninitialised value of size 8`. I guessed the compiler indicated b is initialized? What should I do to correct it?

```
void update(int *x){
  int *b;
  *b=16;
  printf("%d  ",*b);
}
int main() {
  int a=4l;
  int *b=&a;
  printf("%d  ",*b);
  update(&a);
  printf("%d",*b);
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you~

Comment: What’s `x` used for?

Comment: @DavisHerring I used it later. I'm doing an experiment on my code to learn XD

Comment: `int b_val; int *b = &b_val;` You can't do it without an `int` variable somewhere. The pointer needs to point to a valid memory location. Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In update, `b` is the pointer, `*b` is what it points to.  So `*b = 16` is trying to set what b points to, which isn't anything since b is not initialized

Comment: @stark ummm so I have to initialize `b` with another int variable?

Comment: I have no idea what you want b to point to, but before you use b it must point somewhere valid.  That means you must set b before you can use *b

Comment: @stark I see. Thanks!

Comment: If you want b to have random memory, simply you could declare a variable of int type that is never used in the program and point to that location. You need to initialize the pointer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is throwing an error because you're attempting to deference a pointer that was never initialized.

The 'of size 8' most likely means that your system uses 8-byte (64-bit) pointers.

To fix this problem, initialize the pointer to some valid (or invalid if you really prefer) memory location.

Comment: Oh thank you~ so I have to initialize the pointer by another int variable or malloc() or just NULL?

Comment: You could do something like `int *b=NULL` which will most likely segfault, or you could just pick a number like `int *b=0xa107630`, but it is nearly just as likely to segfault. If you want it to run and work, you should use `int *b=malloc(sizeof(int));` or point it to a valid int's address.

Comment: @WillisHershey : Ok, I got that later.

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer but you never tell wich position is, so you can't assign a value. You can fix this problem initializing it first or reserving dynamic memory.

In the first case you can use this:

```
int i;
int *b = &i;//It gets the location of i and saves the value there
*b = 16;
```

And with dynamic memory

```
int *b = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
//it reserves memory to store one int, malloc return the position of the memory you reserved
*b = 16;
```